# exporting jupyter ipython notebook to pdf

Tags: python, pdf, export, jupyter

I'm trying to export a ipython notebook from jupyter to pdf but it just dosen't want to work. First I had some trouble with `pandoc`, but after installing that and adding it to `PATH` I'm still getting a error I don't understand.

```
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(notebook.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size11.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lm\t1lmr.fd"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\mathpazo.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\xetex.def")))
("C:\Users\Sito\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\caption\caption.sty"
("C:\Users\Sito\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\caption\caption3.sty"
))
("C:\Users\Sito\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\adjustbox.s
ty" ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex")))
("C:\Users\Sito\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\adjcalc.sty
")
("C:\Users\Sito\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\trimclip.st
y"
======================================================================
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Users\Sito\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9"
package repository: http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
visiting repository http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
repository type: remote package repository
loading lightweight database...
downloading http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
167630 bytes, 574.39 KB/Sec
lightweight database digest: d071dd32f4cea419134839a73013ff85
going to download 282583 bytes
going to install 5 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/collectbox.tar.lzma...
282583 bytes, 2603.40 KB/Sec
extracting files from collectbox.tar.lzma...

Unfortunately, the package collectbox could not be installed.Please check the log file:
C:/Users/Sito/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/xelatex.log
======================================================================

("C:\Users\Sito\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\collectbox\collectbox
.sty")
("C:\Users\Sito\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\tc-xetex.de
f")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ltxmisc\varwidth.sty"))

! LaTeX Error: File `xcolor.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.43     \usepackage
                    {enumerate} % Needed for markdown enumerations to work^^M
No pages of output.
Transcript written on notebook.log.
```

To be honest, I'm still completly new to jupyter and in general not really experienced in coding so please can someone explain the error to me and what I need to do to solve the problem.

Thanks Sito!

Comment: Alright, took me a while but in the end i just needed to install all the missing packages from MikTeX Package Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter uses a combination of `pandoc` and a TeX distribution to generate PDF files from notebooks.

Your TeX distribution (MiKTeX) is missing the [LaTeX xcolor package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor?lang=en).  Use the [MiTeX package manager](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html) which is causing the collectbox package installation to fail.

Use the MiKTeX package manager to install xcolor, then collect box and try running your conversion again.

Comment: Thanks for the help! 
It worked out but know I have another question. Is it possible to change the "style" of the output-pdf. I'd love to erase the `In[]`
 in ervery line, change the font and especially have the standard latex-font (looks horrible the way it is know..)

Comment: Try looking at alternate templates in nbconvert (http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/)
and customizing nbconvert (http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html). Another alternative would be go notebook to latex and then customize the latex after it's generated.